# How to use filter with data from another scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

below is my code in jsfiddle. I want to apply filter where will be shown documents(2nd scope) only with selected types(1st scope). 
I want to use `filter` in `ng-repeat` but i didn't find example of code with that feachure.

[Jsfiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/j696xf5j/3/)

Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different scopes is not the issue, you just need to apply the state of the `checked` property of each type to the list of documents. This can be done using a filter function:

```
$scope.filterDocuments = function(doc) {
  // Check for All selected
  if ($scope.types.all.checked) {
    return true;
  }

  // Check for individual type selected
  var documentTypeSelected = false;
  for (var t in $scope.types) {
    var type = $scope.types[t];
    if (doc.type_id == type.id) {
      documentTypeSelected = type.checked;
      break;
    }
  }
  return documentTypeSelected;
};
```

Then apply the filter function in the `ng-repeat` for the list of documents:

```
<tr ng-repeat="document in documents | filter:filterDocuments">
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j696xf5j/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try taking help from event handling techniques.
$Emit,$broadcast and $on

Comment: O know how to make it through event handlers, but i want to make it through `filter` because it's less code and much faster to realize next time.

Comment: Event Handlers will help you travel data in between two controllers

Comment: later on that data apply filter

Comment: It's all in one controller.

Comment: then how did a different scope came into play

Comment: You can watch it in linked Fiddle.